# Python MySQL DB

Tags: python

I have 4 tables in a Mysql Db named Employee. The structure of the tables are as follows:

Edetails(***id,name,age***)
Edepartment(***id,name,dept***)
Edesignation(***id,name,desig***)
Esalary(***id,name,basic,pf***)

id is the primary key in all the tables. My question is when a user gives the id of an employee  how can i fetch ***id,name,age,basic,pf*** all at a time??
 I have created all tables and added entries using python. for fetching i used the below code.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb  
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Employee')  
cur=con.cursor()  
x=raw_input("Enter Employee id:")  
cur.execute("Select * from Edepartment,Edesignation,Esalary,Edetails where dept.id=%s",(id))    
res=cur.fetchall()  
print res
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried any query?

Comment: Apart from showing no effort to solve the problem, this is also clearly an SQL question not a Python one.

Comment: I am new to this site.. im sure i will correct the way of asking questions.. or else guide me to correct it.. i edited the question.. i hope now im clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchall()` method gives you all rows in a set. Even if the result set contains one record, you still have to do something like the following

```
import MySQLdb as mdb  
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Employee')  
cur=con.cursor()  
x=raw_input("Enter Employee id:")  
cur.execute("Select table1.id, table2.name from table1,table2 where dept.id=%s",(id))    

results=cur.fetchall()
for result in results:
    print 'id = %s' % result[0]
    print 'name = %s' % result[1]
```

Comment: I dint get output.. the output is as follows:                     Enter Employee id:1     
()